# The difference between domain and server URL in macOS and Windows

Tags: linux, macos, dns, active-directory

Working on windows machine, I manage to gain the credentials of AD user by the following UPN `user@domain`, whereas in Mac I need to put the server name instead of domain, meaning `user@server`.

Here's an example from macOS :

```
> odutil show nodenames # to obtain the domain/server
..
/Active Directory/MYDOMAIN/myserver.com
..
```

in this case, in order to apply to user from domain MYDOMAIN, I need to connect through the following UPN : user@myserver.com (and making sure that the server is accessible via dns of course)

Perhaps anyone can tell me the reason for this difference of behaviour between those 2 platforms ?

Comment: What kind of server are you talking about? AD domain controller? SMB file server? Are you talking about OS logins or about `kinit` or about file share access? When you say `user@domain`, is that the short one-word NetBIOS domain name or the long DNS domain name? Your current made-up examples are very difficult to interpret.

Comment: @grawity, 1. `myserver.com` is AD domain controller which holds the users+credentials. 2. I'm talking about OS login. 3. `user@domain` in macOS is in fact `user@myserver.com` and I wish to know why is that so in macOS (I can assume that in windows it has some way to get the server address from domain unlike macOS)

Comment: I think that the Mac cannot query the AD server for the account info, so you need to specify instead the computer.

Comment: @harrymc, I agree but I couldn't find any documentation that strengthen this claim. if you find anything please share it here. thanks.

Comment: @Zohar81: Sorry but that didn't really clarify much. In Windows, do you use the short dot-less domain like `user@EXAMPLE` or the long domain like `user@ad.example.com`?

Comment: Are you looking to [join AD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/319672)?

Comment: @grawity, I meant the short dot-less format.

Comment: Okay, and in macOS, are you using the name of a specific DC (like `@dc01.ad.example.com`) or the name of the whole domain (like `@ad.example.com`)?